# AEM Internal Redirect

Tags: redirect, mapping, aem, sling

I'm trying to do an internal redirect in AEM 6.3, what I'm trying to do is: any request coming to **localhost:4502/aem** should be redirected to **localhost:4502/content/myapp/en/login.html**. So I created a sling:mapping node under **/etc/map/http/**:

```
jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"  
sling:internalRedirect=/content/myapp/en/login.html -> Type String
sling:match=localhost.4502/aem -> Type String
```

I'm getting an Internal Server Error: **Cannot serve request to /aem on this server**. But if I add the **.html** suffix (request to **localhost:4502/aem.html** it works and redirects correctly.

Also tried:

```
sling:match=localhost.4502/aem(.*)(/.*)?
```

I wonder what I'm missing/doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your first example works for me. Have you tried to create this redirect for a different url like localhost:4503/mytest123? Maybe /aem is captured already somewhere else. You should also test it with a fresh plain AEM installation - just to exclude any interferences with your project.

Comment: I am wondering why you are doing this? AEM authentication can be extended. So you might not need your "own" login page. And redirecting _every_ request to /aem to your login page is also sub-optimal since this would also apply to users that are already logged in.

Comment: It is also working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using **sling:redirect** instead of **sling:internalRedirect**, not sure if this is the proper solution, but is working:

```
jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"  
sling:redirect=localhost:4502/content/myapp/en/login.html -> Type String
sling:match=localhost.4502/aem -> Type String
```

If you have a better option, feel free posting it, Thanks.

Comment: This will only work if the entered URL strictly matches localhost:4502/aem or localhost:4502/aem.html and not if the URL is like localhost:4502/aem/start.html. Maybe you can change the regex to sling:match=localhost.4502/aem(.*)(/.*)?. For me both methods work fine. sling:redirect will cause another request and a page reload while sling:internalRedirect won't reload the page. Choose as per your requirements.

Comment: Although both methods work for me too, I think for your purpose, ideally you should use sling:internalRedirect since your page is not external to AEM. When you tried the internalRedirect did you try to name the folder "localhost"?
I used the exact same config you mentioned and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go to http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver to check whether your redirects are correct or incorrect!

for example your 
CRXDE **Internal URL** is http://localhost:4502/content/app1/en-in/home.html
and preferred **external URL** is http://localhost:4502/home/

There are to options you will be able to see

map: 
map returns you the external URL when you enter internal URL. Remember to add .html at the end.

resolve: 
resolve does the reverse of map. Remember to add .html at the end while testing.